# Merging patient data based on IDs from 4 dimensions into 1 new dimension - there are problems however

Tags: join, ssis, merge, dimensions

I have 4 dimensions with patient data. In each dimension there's an ID for the patients. The only problem is that I have no idea how to merge the 4 dimensions into 1 new dimension.

I would use a merge join, but that doesn't work since I also have patient records with no ID. I can't match the patient records to anything if they don't have an ID. Also, there's patients that have IDs in 2 out of the 4 dimensions only, so how do I load that into my new dimension?

Comment: And what if you have conflicting values from dim1 vs dim2 and dim4 and pity dim3 didn't have any record for that id. Then what? What are your survivorship rules?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, if you are importing business object data from multiple sources, you generate a new ID in your data warehouse for each business object. Then you code the business rules into SSIS that match resolve the conflicts and merge the appropriate records.

Comment: i agree, but i just don't know where to start though.

Comment: Add a RowID column to your data warehouse dimension table - make it an Identity field that auto-populates. Fill it with the appropriate dimension records using SSIS. Then when you populate the Fact table, use this RowID instead of the IDs on the incoming fact records.